# Is the docker ENTRYPOINT path in Dockerfile is different that the others?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following this tutorial : https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#postgres . But I have a problem when it come to definine an entrypoint in the Dockerfile. I used absolute path to point the entrypoint.sh path everywhere and it work except for the ENTRYPOINT of Dockerfile :

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /mnt/c/Users/titou/Documents/OC/p10/code/pur_beurre

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /mnt/c/Users/titou/Documents/OC/p10/code/pur_beurre/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /mnt/c/Users/titou/Documents/OC/p10/code/pur_beurre/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/mnt/c/Users/titou/Documents/OC/p10/code/pur_beurre/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I have this error :

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/mnt/c/Users/titou/Documents/OC/p10/code/pur_beurre/entrypoint.sh": stat /mnt/c/Users/titou/Documents/OC/p10/code/pur_beurre/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Note : My os is Windows but my terminal is a WSL2 under Ubuntu. I got the path using pwd command.

Comment: Entrypoint reads the same file system. So if the absolute path works before it should also work in the entrypoint. I would suggest to simplify the path, its quite weird to read /mnt/c/... in a dockerfile. You also use a workdir, using the absolute path everywhere is kinda redundant. *You* are already right there. If you make the entrypoint executable on your host system it will also be exectuable when you copy it in the build container. All of those things dont really explain your problem though.

Comment: What is the very very first line of the file?  (It should be something like `#!/bin/sh`; if it names `bash` instead, that doesn't exist in an Alpine-based image.)  How are you running the container?  (If you use a `docker run -v` option to overwrite the image's content with local files, things like the line ending conversion will get lost.)

Comment: @DavidMaze The first line of entrypoint.sh ? It is not a comment, it is a if statement : ```if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]```

Comment: @TheFool Ok so I applied your advice and that fixed the issue ! Seems like entry point does not work with absolute path

Comment: entrypoint does certainly work with absolute path. Maybe you are getting confused with the way you copy stuff and where it ends up inside the image.

Comment: and @DavidMaze is right. An executable script should have as first line a [shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang)